# What does this Kotlin code for an Android app do?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am following a tutorial and in the `NewChatroomDialog.kt` fragment class, and I have this code:

```
 mCreateChatroom!!.setOnClickListener {
    ...
    (activity as ChatActivity).init()
    ...
 }
```

The `init()` method is implemented in the `ChatActivity.kt` Android activity:

```
fun init() {

   ...

   mFob!!.setOnClickListener {
        val dialog = NewChatroomDialog()
        dialog.show(supportFragmentManager, getString(R.string.dialog_new_chatroom))
   }
}
```

Now I understand (but I might be wrong) two things here:

1. the variable `activity` is cast to type `ChatActivity`, and
2. the `init()`, there is an extension function of the `ChatActivity.kt` class

Am I correct about these two things, and am I missing anything in my understanding of this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You understood it pretty well, except by that the `init()` is not exactly an extension function. The variable `activity` is the current activity instance where the fragment is attached to (it is what in java `getActivity();` returns) and it is casting just to call the `init()` function;

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain this to me!